What sci-fi tropes have never appeared in the Star Wars franchise?
Star Wars, one of the most exhaustive science fiction franchises of all time, has explored almost every sci-fi concept in the book. Time travel does exist in both Legends and Canon (The World Between Worlds for the latter), and you can argue they explored First Contact (or a form of it) in Legends with the Yuuzhan Vong and they did explore other timelines with the Star Wars Legends Infinities comics.
The only 2 tropes I can think of that they haven’t done yet is:
• Mecha (like in Gundam)
• Gender Bender
Are there any more?
